# How do I define URL query parameters in my Body Mapping Template in AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

My api is of the form:

```
https://<>.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Testing/api/v1/mobs/<>.json?filename=<>.json&assertion=1
```

Currently, I have just defined till the `.../mobs/<>.json` in my Mapping Template, like this:

```
{
    "mob_type": "$input.params('type')"
}
```

Now, I added query parameters to the url, which are `filename` and `assertion`.  So, how do I define them in the Body Mapping Template?

This, doesn't work:

```
{
    "mob_type": "$input.params('type')"
    "filename": "$input.params('filename')"
    "assertion": "$input.params('assertion')"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the Integration Request under "URL Query String Parameters", you need to add a mapping for

- method.request.querystring.type
- method.request.querystring.filename
- method.request.querystring.assertion

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html#mapping-request-parameters

With the mapping, they are accessible in the Body Mapping Templates.